# Symbol PhoneCall.getPhoneNumber not found in BlackBerry Bold 9000 simulator

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry application development.I am trying to retrieve the incoming call number in my application and its working fine with Blackberry curve device and Blackberry touch simulator, But while running this application on BlackBerry Simulator Bold 9000 it shows "Run time Exception" and "Error starting :Symbol PhoneCall.getPhoneNumber is not found" like this, here is my code,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.AbstractPhoneListener;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.Phone;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.PhoneCall;
import net.rim.device.api.system.RadioInfo;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

/**
* This class extends the UiApplication class, providing a
* graphical user interface.
*/
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
/**
 * Entry point for application
 * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
 */ 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
    // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
    MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}


/**
 * Creates a new MyApp object
 */
public MyApp()
{        

    // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
    pushScreen(new HomeScreen());
    Phone.addPhoneListener(new PhoneCallInterceptor());
}    
}
final class PhoneCallInterceptor extends AbstractPhoneListener {

public PhoneCallInterceptor() {

}

public void callIncoming(final int callId) {

    final PhoneCall call = Phone.getCall(callId);  
    final String number = call.getPhoneNumber();    //Here its throws an error.

  }
}
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhoneCall](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneCall.html).getPhoneNumber() was added in OS 4.7.   You BlackBerry 9000 simulator is likely running OS 4.6, so this method isn't present.  The best alternative to use is [PhoneCall](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneCall.html).getDisplayPhoneNumber() but that will only give you the phone number if the number doesn't match any user in the device contact list.  When the number matches a contact, you will get the contact name instead.